# Specify Oracle Client in Connection String

Tags: oracle

I have two Oracle clients installed on my 32-bit developer machine (12.1.0.4 and 11.2). I have both installed with ODT with ODAC. I am using ODP.NET with the version 12 client for most of the newer applications that connect to newer Oracle databases. But I have legacy code that connects to an Oracle 9 database, and does so through System.Data.OracleClient. The version 12 client is too new to connect to Oracle 9.

My ODP.NET apps work fine. However, I can't get my legacy code to connect to the Oracle 9 database, if the version 12 client is on my machine. I have tried to set the ORACLE_HOME and PATH environment variables, but it has had no effect. When the connection is attempted it is still trying to use the Version 12 client and fails. If I uninstall the version 12 client, the version 11 client works fine.

Is there a way in the connection string for System.Data.OracleClient to specify which client to use, or is there another way to achieve what I need to do?

Comment: Why not only using 11.2? With this you can connect to any DB.

Comment: Try to copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll to folder of your application. Specify version in project file.

Comment: Have also a look at registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET\...\DllPath`

Comment: I would love to run 11.2, but ODT installation for 11.2 stinks, and does not give you the same options as 12 one.

Comment: I have a 11g (good old Oracle Discoverer) and a 12c client.  I just change my Oracle Home and that has always worked. I see you have tried that. Do you have TNS_ADMIN defined or not? Could this help?